# How can i pass authroziation token in header with multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js

I am using reactjs in my front end, so I am converting an image into base64 data and pass it to nodejs, In my backend I am trying send the base64 data to 3rd part API using fetch call, But it returns

> 401 unauthorization error

If I pass authorization in header nothing happens

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', url);

    const resp = await fetch(requestURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': accessToken,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    body: formData,
    });
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Plz give more info with this nobody solve your problem

Comment: Can you please tell me what info you need